# My HTML/CSS graph bars are generated from upward towards down which is wrong?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to generate graph bars so far I got to the stage where I can generate beautiful graph bars but the problem is that the graphs are generated from upward towards down which is totally wrong for instance have a look at following snippet:

**Note :** I want the graphs to get generated from down towards upside so how can I achieve this in CSS not in CSS3/HTML5 please?

**IMP :** Please the solution should avoid the use of **flex** properties in CSS.

```css
.chart { 
 overflow: hidden;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 89.5px;
}
.bar-container {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 300px;
    display:list-item;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.bar {
    background-color: #e8ba45;
    width: 31px;
    text-align: center;
}
.linux {
    background-color: #f03748;
}
.macos {
    background-color: #1b4a52;
}
.balloon-text {
 color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 13px;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart">
    <div class="bar-container">
     <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:30% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
     <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:10% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
     <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
     <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:20% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
     <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
     <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
     <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
     <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
     <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
     <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
     <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
     <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
     <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why does the first set of divs use `padding`, when the rest uses `height`? Is it the result of you doing some experimenting, or is there another reason?

Comment: @PeterB : I want to vertically align the text under there with that so is there any other possible way to vertically align the text in the div bars? as you can see the `5,4,3` are vertically aligned in the bars divs!

Comment: I understand what you need, but you did not answer my question.

Comment: @PeterB : Yes sorry about that the rest are old ones where I haven't yet embedded the texts to vertically aligned in there that's why it's using height but if you can make it work with heights that is also great but the text should be vertically aligned in center.

Comment: @PeterB : I have updated the code, Please have a look over it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like the solution with [`display: flex;`](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox), then you can try to use [table positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Browser_compatibility) together with [`vertical-align:bottom;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align#Syntax):

```css
.chart { 
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 89.5px;
}
.bar-container {
    margin-right: 4px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
.bar {
    background-color: #e8ba45;
    width: 31px;
    text-align: center;
}
.linux {
    background-color: #f03748;
}
.macos {
    background-color: #1b4a52;
}

.balloon-text {
   color: white;
    top: 13px;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
}

.ballon-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart">
    <div class="bar-container">
        <div class="ballon-wrapper">
          <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        </div>
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:30% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
        <div class="ballon-wrapper">
          <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        </div>
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:10% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
        <div class="ballon-wrapper">
          <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        </div>
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
        <div class="ballon-wrapper">
          <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        </div>
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:20% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
        <div class="ballon-wrapper">
          <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        </div>
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
        <div class="ballon-wrapper">
          <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        </div>
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
        <div class="ballon-wrapper">
          <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        </div>
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
        <div class="ballon-wrapper">
          <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        </div>
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
        <div class="ballon-wrapper">
          <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        </div>
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
        <div class="ballon-wrapper">
          <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        </div>
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
        <div class="ballon-wrapper">
          <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        </div>
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
        <div class="ballon-wrapper">
          <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        </div>
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
        <div class="ballon-wrapper">
          <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        </div>
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using absolute and relatively positioned elements, but perhaps another way that doesn't change your structure too much is to simply add an "invisible" bar at the top that takes up the remaining space which effectively pushes the other bars down to the bottom (I also increased the height of your chart and bar-container as the bottom was being cut off). Something like this:

```css
.chart { 
 overflow: hidden;
    height: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 89.5px;
}
.bar-container {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 350px;
    display:list-item;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.bar {
    background-color: #e8ba45;
    width: 31px;
    text-align: center;
}
.linux {
    background-color: #f03748;
}
.macos {
    background-color: #1b4a52;
}
.top-fill {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.balloon-text {
 color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 13px;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart">
    <div class="bar-container">
     <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        <div class="bar top-fill" style="padding:70% 0;"></div>
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:30% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
     <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        <div class="bar top-fill" style="padding:30% 0;"></div>
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:10% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
     <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
     <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        <div class="bar top-fill" style="padding:20% 0;"></div>
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:20% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
     <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
     <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
     <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
     <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
     <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
     <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
     <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
     <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
     <div class="ff3 balloon-text">12</div>
     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n2Njev/graph_bar_balloon.png" style="width: 35px;">
        <div class="bar windows" style="padding:50% 0;">5</div>
        <div class="bar linux" style="padding:40% 0;">4</div>
        <div class="bar macos" style="padding:100% 0;">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The balloons are not in the right place which is a problem.